# Caesar cipher looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, caesar-cipher, python-3.10

I have some code which has other problems as well at the moment but I'm really struggling with the looping part (going from z back to a).

I've looked at a buch of other answers but found none that actually helped in my situation.

```
import string
upper = string.ascii_uppercase
lower = string.ascii_lowercase
digit = string.digits
letters = string.ascii_letters


delrv = input("Vill du kryptera, skriv K. Vill du dekryptera, skriv D")
inm = input("Skriv en text eller siffror")
nyckel = (input("Ange nycklar"))
lista = []
listad = []

splitNyckel = nyckel.split(" ")
splitNyckel = [int(a) for a in splitNyckel]

#kryptering
if(delrv == "K" or delrv == "k"):
    for i in range(len(inm)):
        #for a in range(len(splitNyckel)):
            #rakning = ord(inm[i]) + 1
            #if(rakning == 90):
            
            #elif(rakning == 122):

        if(ord(inm[i]) + splitNyckel[i] == 90):
            lista[i] = 65
        elif(ord(inm[i]) + splitNyckel[i] == 122):
            lista[i] = 97
        lista.append(ord(inm[i]) + splitNyckel[i])
        print(chr(lista[i]))



#Dekryptering
if(delrv == "D" or delrv == "d"):
    for i in range(len(inm)):
        lista.append(ord(inm[i]) - splitNyckel[i])
        print(chr(lista[i]))
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I've created a simple step-by-step explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60529096/589259) in case you want to perform the coding yourself. In short: first convert the character to an index in the alphabet (in this case the ABC) starting at index zero. Then you can perform modular addition / subtraction with the key on that index. Then finally convert the result back to a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

The most basic would be to just subtract 26 anytime you go past the range you are trying to stay within.  Or in the case of shifting the other direction and ending up somewhere before a/A, you could add 26 instead.

Another option would be to use the mod operator to stay within a certain range, e.g. `(some_val - ord('a')) % 26 + ord('a')` would keep you within the range of `ord('a')` and `ord('z')`.  This would have an advantage over pure addition or subtraction in that it would work for shifts greater than 26 as well.

Comment: Where in my current code would you put (some_val - ord('a')) % 26 + ord('a') and what would some_val be replaced with?

Comment: I'd not do this, I would use `index = ord(char) - ord('a')`, followed by `coded_index = (index + key) % 26` and finally `coded_char = chr(coded_index + ord('a')`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: `some_val` would be the ord of your plaintext character plus the shift amount.  I believe that is `ord(inm[i]) + splitNyckel[i]` in your code.  Maarten's solution works as well—it is essentially doing the same thing, but broken down into steps so it is more readable, and also includes the starting and ending steps of converting to and from the numeric ASCII values.